# Dynamic module importing

Tags: python, json, import, module

I have several custom python modules that perform specific functions (data parsing, computations, etc...). I then have json configurations that describe a module (i.e. module name, arguments, functions, etc...). Finally, I am creating a driver script that I want to drive these modules. The configurations more or less are passed to the driver which commands the module to run certain functions based on this config. What I want to do is based on these configurations I would like to dynamically import these modules and run through the list of tests that is provided based on the configs. The number of configs can be anywhere from 1 to N. The list of tests would be either hardcoded because the modules are created based on a template or provided via the config.

i.e.
JsonFile:

```
{ <module_name>: {
    kw:<module>,
    kw:<arg1>,
    kw:<argN>
    }
 }
```

Code:

```
<parse json code>
for key,val in jsonCfg.items():
    lst.append(key)
    for dctKey, itm in val.items():
        if 'IMPORT' in dctkey:
            importlib.import_module(itm)
```

That is the basics of what I have so far... I am getting stuck now on how to command python to call that modules code.  I was hoping to have something like a standard import...

```
import <module> as <module_name>
```

Where module would be the itm and module_name would be the key. This way I can iterate through my keys for as many as I have and call the standard functions of those modules.

i.e. It should function like this...

```
import moduleX as MX
MX.execute
import moduleY as MY
MY.execute
```

But be coded like...(pseudo-code)

```
<parse json code>
for key,val in jsonCfg.items():
    lst.append(key)
    for dctKey, itm in val.items():
        if 'IMPORT' in dctkey:
            importlib.import_module(itm) as key
for mod in lst.items()
   mod.execute()
```

I hope this makes sense and if not just comment so I can make clarify as needed.

Comment: Isn't each script executed on importing it if it hasn't got anything like `if __name__ == '__main__'` anyway?

Comment: [`import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) returns a module object, so what's the problem with `mod = importlib.import_module(itm)` and then later call whatever function of the module you like using `mod.func(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`importlib.import_module` returns a reference the imported module object, you just have to create a new variable and store it to be able to access the members:

```
x = importlib.import_module(module_name)
x.some_func()
```

If you have multiple names you can store the imported modules in some structure, a list or dict, whatever makes sense for you:

```
dynamods = {}
for key, val in jsonCfg.items():
    for dctKey, itm in val.items():
        if 'IMPORT' in dctkey:
            dynamods[key] = importlib.import_module(itm)
```

Then you can use it to call a function:

```
for mod in dynamods
    dynamods[mod].execute()
```